# Cascade Delete EF Core and Cross Tables

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I have a Address model, its used to all models in my system, like this:

```
class Person
{
    public IList<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        PersonAddresses = new List<PersonAddress>();
    }
}

class PersonAddress
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address 
{
   //...
}
```

and in OnModelCreating:

```
builder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
            .HasKey(pa => new { pa.PersonId, pa.AddressId });
```

and its works very fine! My only question is about cascade deleting. How I do to setup this scenario:

- When deleting a Person, cascade-delete the PersonAddress and Addresses
- When deleting a Address, cascade-delete the PersonAddress and NOT the Person

Currently I see that deleting the Person will delete the PersonAddress (but not the related Address).

I'm not complaining about the behaviour, but is not clear to me how I do the setup to auto-cascade-delete the entities as I want OR if I will need perform the deletings manually.

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete an address when you delete a person? Couldn't there be multiple people at that address? If not, you didn't need to create the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Tim I understand you, but 1 person have N address, and I have other entities that relates with Address like this. By example, Customer, CustomerAddress, Vendor, VendorAddress, etc... all entities share the same Address entity.

Comment: But couldn't `Customer`, `Person`, and `Vendor` all just have a `List<Address>`?

Comment: @Tim Then EF Core will create one table for each, like CustomerAddress, PersonAddress and VendorAddress. And I want all Addresses in only one table "Addresses"

Comment: There are ways around that, such as replacing `PersonId` with a generic `EntityId` in the `Address` class, and mapping to each different type of user entity.

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense with the provided model. The model represents a typical many-to-many relationship. Which means that one and the same address can be associated with many people, hence deleting person cannot delete address, because simply the address is not owned by that single person.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` or `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` extensions with the fluent api.

```
builder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
            .HasKey(pa => new { pa.PersonId, pa.AddressId })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```